# PHP Table 2D Leap year

Tags: php, html-table

I have a following problem:
I need to create a 2D table from year 1990 to 2014. If that year is leap year, it goes on the right side, if not, on the right:

[image: table]

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<1;$i++) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "Leto je prestopno" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "Leto ni prestopno" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    for($j=0;$j<12;$j++){

    }
}
echo "<table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this

```
function is_leap_year($year)
{
    return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year %400) == 0)));
}

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>Leap Year</th><th>Not Leap Year</th></tr>';
for($i = 1990; $i < 2015; $i++){
    if(is_leap_year($i)){
        $left_td = $i;
        $right_td = '-';
    }else{
        $left_td = '-';
        $right_td = $i;
    }
    echo '<tr><td>'.$left_td.'</td><td>'.$right_td.'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```